# brctl addbr and bonding not working for CentOS6 if IPv6 is disabled

Tags: centos6, ipv6, bridge, rhel6, bonding

I set up a CentOS6-XEN4-Server according to [**these**](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart) instructions.

Now I want to set up bridges - first manually:

`brctl addbr test` - but this fails with:

"add Bridge failed: Package not installed"

Googling about that I tried to manually `modprobe bridge` which triggers an error that is caused-according to `dmesg` by:

> bridge: Unknown symbol ipv6_dev_get_saddr (err 0)

`modinfo bridge` reveals that the bridge-modules depends on stp,llc and ipv6.

Great. I do not want IPv6, I do not need IPv6 and have blacklisted IPv6.

1. Is there any way to get `brctl` running without enabling IPv6?
2. Why is that depency there at all?

**Update** 2014-05-14

I found this to be a general CentOS 6/RH 6 problem. It also applies to the **bonding** module.

The accepted answer describes the root-cause - so this problem will also arise on comparable kernel-versions and is not restricted to CentOS/RedHat/Scentific Linux 6.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 is a serious mistake. You _do_ need it, if not today (or even years ago!) then very soon.

Comment: @MichaelHampton on directly internet connected systems maybe. On intranet, linux-systems - nope.

Comment: You need it even more on internal systems! Perhaps you don't yet understand IPv6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has been discussed on the kernel ML and the conclusion was that users shouldn't disable ipv6 anymore.

quoted from https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=685053

The workaround for this situation is to not blacklist the ipv6 module, but rather set its disable_ipv6 module option. That way the code gets loaded, but no ipv6 functionality is registered with the kernel so user space can't accesses it.

**Update** 2014-05-14:

The correct workaround seems to be:

1. Un-blacklist **ipv6** and **net-pf-10**
2. create **/etc/modprobe.d/ipv6.conf** with the following content:

   options ipv6 disable_ipv6=1

Comment: Excellent reference - although I would not name RH-bugzilla a kernel-ML. Interesting option for the IPv6-module.

Comment: i was actually referring to another ML (LKML) where this topic has been discussed as well.

Comment: BTW: There seems to exist the same problem with the bonding-module.